# php preg_match_all of multiple lines pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm stuck at this question and hope any one out there can help me.

I have a config file that contains following lines:

```
config system interface
edit "internal1"
    set vdom "root"
    set ip 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
    set allowaccess ping https ssh http fgfm capwap
    set type physical
    set snmp-index 1
next
edit "internal2"
    set vdom "root"
    set ip 192.168.20.2 255.255.255.0
    set allowaccess ping https ssh http fgfm capwap
    set type physical
    set snmp-index 2
    Set secondary-IP enable
      config secondaryip
        edit 1
          set ip 192.168.21.2 255.255.255.0
        next
        edit 2
          set ip 192.168.22.2 255.255.255.0
        next
      end
next
edit "internal3"
    set vdom "root"
    set ip 192.168.30.3 255.255.255.0
    set allowaccess ping https ssh http fgfm capwap
    set type physical
    set snmp-index 3
    Set secondary-IP enable
      config secondaryip
        edit 1
          set ip 192.168.31.3 255.255.255.0
        next
      end
next
end
....
```

And want to Match for interface's Name, vdom, vlanid, ip and secondary-ip(s) with following regex:

```
preg_match_all("/edit .+(\s+config secondaryip\r?\n(\s+edit \d+\r?\n.+\s+next\r?\n){1,}\s+end\r?\n)?.+next\r?\n/s", $configFile, $matched_interfaces);
```

with the first `.+` is everything matched and not the others!

Thx for any suggestions

Comment: Make it less greedy. That being said, this file structure does not lend itself to extract-all-at-once. With possibly arbitrary ordering and nesting, some tokenization and state machine would be advisable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love regex

```
$regex = '/(?<=\vedit ")(\w+)|(?<=vdom ")(\w+)|(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?=\s+set)|(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?=\s+next)/';
print_r(preg_match_all($regex, $configFile, $matched_interfaces));
```

Output is

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[0] => internal1
[1] => root
[2] => 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
[3] => internal2
[4] => root
[5] => 192.168.20.2 255.255.255.0
[6] => 192.168.21.2 255.255.255.0
[7] => 192.168.22.2 255.255.255.0
[8] => internal3
[9] => root
[10] => 192.168.30.3 255.255.255.0
[11] => 192.168.31.3 255.255.255.0
)

[1] => Array
(
[0] => internal1
[1] => 
[2] => 
[3] => internal2
[4] => 
[5] => 
[6] => 
[7] => 
[8] => internal3
[9] => 
[10] => 
[11] => 
)

[2] => Array
(
[0] => 
[1] => root
[2] => 
[3] => 
[4] => root
[5] => 
[6] => 
[7] => 
[8] => 
[9] => root
[10] => 
[11] => 
)

[3] => Array
(
[0] => 
[1] => 
[2] => 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
[3] => 
[4] => 
[5] => 192.168.20.2 255.255.255.0
[6] => 
[7] => 
[8] => 
[9] => 
[10] => 192.168.30.3 255.255.255.0
[11] => 
)

[4] => Array
(
[0] => 
[1] => 
[2] => 
[3] => 
[4] => 
[5] => 
[6] => 192.168.21.2 255.255.255.0
[7] => 192.168.22.2 255.255.255.0
[8] => 
[9] => 
[10] => 
[11] => 192.168.31.3 255.255.255.0
)

)
```

**Edit to answer follow up**

`(?<=\vedit ")` This is a positive look behind construct, and has to be in parenthesis. This bit `?<=` specifies its a positive look behind `\v` matches vertical whitespace and `edit "` literally matches edit ". This is followed by `(\w+)` which means match word characters as many times as you can, putting it in parenthesis creates a capture group so you can reference the match later. The positive look behind means that the `(\w+)` pattern will only match if the look behind sequence immediately before it also matches

You can add group names to your capture groups to have them returned as a named array

```
$regex = '/(?<=edit ")(?<name>\w+)\K|(?<=vdom ")(?<vdom>\w+)|(?<ip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?=\s+set)|(?<secondary>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?=\s+next)\K/';
```

Comment: Many thx miknik!! Could you give me a short explanation of "<?<=\v" and how can I make the match array associative with the corresponding key?